# É possível fazer colspan no DataTables?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-datatables

Tenho a seguinte estrutura em `PHP` que implementa uma tabela:

```
foreach ($varConsulta as $lin) {
    $var1= $varConsulta[$i]['1'];
    $var2= $varConsulta[$i]['2'];
    $var3= $varConsulta[$i]['3'];
    $varFase= $varConsulta[$i]['FASE'];

    $linhas = "";
    $linhas .= "<td style='padding: 10px;'>" . utf8_encode($var1) . "</td>";
    $linhas .= "<td style='padding: 10px;'>" . utf8_encode($var2) . "</td>";
    $linhas .= "<td style='padding: 10px;'>" . utf8_encode($var3) . "</td>";

    switch ($varFase) {
        case 1:
            $linhas .= "<td colspan='2'>ALUNO NÃO APROVADO</td>";
            break;
        case 2:
            $linhas .= "<td style='padding: 10px;'><select id='".$var1."' name='".$var1."'><option value=''></option><option value='1'>SIM</option><option value='0'>NÃO</option></select></td>";
            $linhas .= "<td style='text-align: center;'><a href='#' onclick='comparecimento(".$var1.")' class='Adicionar' title='Adicionar'>.</a></td>";
            break;
        case 3:
            $linhas .= "<td colspan='2'>AGUARDANDO RESULTADO</td>";
            break;
    }

    echo "<tr>" . $linhas . "</tr>";
    $i++;
}
```

Gostaria de saber se existe uma configuração do `dataTable` que permita a concatenação de colunas no `corpo da tabela`, e não no `header`

Aqui a configuração padrão que utilizo no `dataTable`:

```
if ($("#lst").length){

    $("#lst").dataTable( {
        "bJQueryUI" : true,
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": 10
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

infelizmente atualmente não é possível realizar colspan nas linhas da tabela pelo datatables, abaixo segue uma explicação dada por um membro da equipe de desenvolvimento:

> I'm sorry to say that DataTables does not support colspan at the
>   moment. The reason for this is that it is very much a non-trivial
>   problem in how this would interact with filtering and sorting (for
>   example how would you sort a column which has elements that span
>   multiple columns - which column would that data belong to? The first
>   one, or all of them? - The same question hangs over filtering).

referência: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/14/datatables-and-colspan

caso necessite de tradução então solicite mas acredito que o google tradutor dá conta do recado.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de fazer isso seria adicionar nas células:

```
<th style="width: 40%;">Nome</th>
<td style="width: 40%;">resultado)</td>
```

Comment: Mas acredito que isso não cria de fato um efeito de `colspan`, somente aumenta a largura da coluna